# How to Compare 2 Columns of Numbers in One Function for an Average

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I'm trying to take a column of numbers, parse them in some way, divide them by another column of numbers in the same row, and return the average of each quotient. For example:
| A | B |
|:-:|:-:|
| 6 |210|
| 8 |225|
| 12|240|

I would like to divide A2 by B2, A3 by B3, etc., and then take the average of every quotient and return it (without manually typing in each division). Is there a simple or effective solution to fix this? Very new to Sheets, so over-simplified explanations/answers are highly appreciated :)

Comment: After A2 divided by B2, such as 6/210, what is the meaning of average of quotient?

Comment: For example, the function for the sample data would return the average of A2/B2, A3/B3, etc. I was asking if there was a way to implement the etc without manually typing each division. For this dataset, the answer would be 27.708333...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sumproduct` to return a single result with the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B3/A1:A3)/COUNTA(B1:B3)
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot use `A:A`, but to select the range, it is the restriction in `Sumproduct`, is it the problem you are facing?